# C# String Does Not Contain Text

Tags: c#, string, contains

I have a phrase that is entered into a textbox similar to this: "What is the weather tomorrow in taree"

At the moment this code sets the *suburb* string to a capitalised name, and sets the *suburbID* to a value.

```
public void requestedSuburb(String suburbFromForm1)
{
    suburb = suburbFromForm1;

    if (suburb.Contains("taree"))
    {
       suburb = "Taree";
       suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
    }
    else if (suburb.Contains("port macquarie"))
    {
       suburb = "Port Macquarie";
       suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
    }
```

(more suburb names are checked with ***else if*** statements below this point.

The whole InputTextbox.Text is passed into the *suburb* string for checking for the above.

My question is, is there an ***else if*** statement that can check the *suburb* string, and if no text of a suburb is found, it can default to a selection? (ie: I want 'Taree' to be the default setting.)

What I have at the moment is this, but it doesn't return anything:

```
else if (!suburb.Contains("taree") || (!suburb.Contains("port macquarie")))
{
   suburb = "Port Macquarie"
   suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
}
```

Comment: `switch`/`case` statement?

Comment: Sounds like a `ComboBox` would be a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need an `else` at the end of all `else-if` like this:

```
if (suburb.Contains("taree"))
{
   suburb = "Taree";
   suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
}
else if (suburb.Contains("port macquarie"))
{
   suburb = "Port Macquarie";
   suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
}
else {
  suburb = "default";
}
```

Comment: 100ms quicker than me :P

Comment: @SimonWhitehead it's just because I might read the question first :)

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly and is nice and simple. I've been playing with code all day, so that one was escaping me.

Answer (score 2):

You just want `else`:

```
if (suburb.Contains("taree"))
{
   suburb = "Taree";
   suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
}
else if (suburb.Contains("port macquarie"))
{
   suburb = "Port Macquarie";
   suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
}
else
{
    // this fires if nothing else above is correct
    suburb = "Taree";
    suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `else` to handle the default setting, like this:

```
if (suburb.Contains("taree"))
{ 
    suburb = "Taree";
    suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
}
else if (suburb.Contains("port macquarie"))
{
    suburb = "Port Macquarie";
    suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
}
else
{
    suburb = "Taree";
    suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";
}
```

---

You can also just assign the default to start with and then only overwrite the default value if a match is found, like this:

```
// Default values
suburb = "Taree";
suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.95784.xml";

if (suburb.Contains("port macquarie")
{
    suburb = "Port Macquarie";
    suburbID = "zmw:00000.1.94787.xml";
}
```

> Note: This simplifies your logic to a single `if` for the example code you posted. This also eliminates duplicate logic in the first `if` and the `else`.

Comment: I think the second approach has a correct idea but you have to modify it a little, we have to copy the `suburb` first (before assigning it with the default `"Taree"`), use that copy in the `else if` and update the `suburb` if the condition is `true`, that way we don't need the last `else`.

Comment: however the OP alread has an argument passed in called `suburbFromForm1`, so we can use that right in the `else-if` without needing to copy the suburb